# CakePHP: where to set default session values?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.2

I have an app that uses CakeSession for saving different user data. Now I want to write some default values using `CakeSession::write()` and have them available for all views (also for cached views). So the check/write should be done on every request before the view is rendered.

But where to put the code to match these requirements? Until now, I tried the following positions to use `CakeSession::write()` but without success:

1. Config/bootstrap.php -> CakeSession is not defined yet
2. AppController::__construct() -> CakeSession is not defined yet
3. AppController::beforeFilter() -> will not be called for cached views

Comment: you can pass `'callbacks'=>true` as a param of `cacheAction` which fires the `beforeFilter`.

Comment: @Ross Thank you for this info. I think this is a possible solution. Can you say something about the performance for cached files when callbacks are fired?

Comment: you'd have to do your own benchmarking, too many factors involved. And this sounds a bit like premature optimization - be aware, but wait until it becomes a problem before worrying too much.

Comment: I was just asking because I was expecting a much higher impact on the performance. But everything works like a charm. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Nowhere will cached views create sessions. A cached view does not initialise a request at all

[docs](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/cache.html#marking-non-cached-content-in-views)

```
It should be noted that once an action is cached, the controller method for the 
action will not be called. When a cache file is created, the request object, 
and view variables are serialized with PHP’s serialize().
```

Comment: Why not? Helpers will be loaded in cached view. Using SessionHelper will make CakeSession available in this view. So the methods of CakeSession can be called in `<!--nocache-->` tags without problems.

Comment: For reading. You can not write to sessions after output has been sent,   and by the time you are in the `<!-- nocache -->` output has been sent.

Comment: in "no cache" pieces you should only READ from the session. you can write to cookies via JS/jquery for example if you need to store sth more persistent.

Comment: `CakeSession::write()` is also possible within `<!--nocache-->`. These tags are just used in the cache (php) file. They are removed during the rendering of the view and all this happens before the output. Because of this, one possible solution can be to create an element within `<!--nocache-->` and put all the CakeSession::write() code in this element. But is an element the correct place to write session data? I mean it's a view...

Comment: you shouldn't be writing session data in a view or element.

Comment: 3 People say you should not be writing sessions in the view is generally a good indication that you should not be writing sessions in the view.

Comment: @dogmatic69 yes, you are absolutely right. I also prefer to handle such data in a controller. In my last comment, I just wanted to point out, that it's not _impossible_ to write session data in (cached) views.